# Serverless Execution Isolation

Tags: serverless-architecture

I am looking at serverless architecture to process some customer data. The process itself is probably quite quick, but for various reasons I would like the cloud service provider to gurantee executional isolation. So far, I've talked to a rep from Amazon, who said that Amazon Lambda are not effectively isolated, and the *lambda container* may end up being reused.

Effectively, when running a function and, say, writing something to memory or disk (here we might not have control, as part of the solution would let customers execute arbitrary code) I would like a sandbox isolation gurantee.

I've read that Microsoft was going to offer such isolation, but apart from a [news story](https://thenewstack.io/azure-functions-serverless-computing-handling-iot-devices/), I couldn't find and concrete information. There they alude to extra costs of sandboxing functions for example.

**So is there any provider that could gurantee executional isolation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) is guaranteeing isolated execution:

> Run in a fully-managed, serverless environment where Google handles
>   infrastructure, operating systems, and runtime environments completely
>   on your behalf. **Each Cloud Function runs in its own isolated secure
>   execution context**, scales automatically, and has a lifecycle
>   independent from other functions.

*Emphasis mine*